# Javascript: calling javaScript function from flash (swfObject)?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, function-calls

let suppose i have  a object named "data" which has a callBack function named "closeItem" which does something.

So i have flash file which has a close button. on click of that i am calling this function which closes this item.

So issue is ?

If i pass this "closeItemFunction" as global function this works fine.

but if  a pass this function as a "data.closeItem" this doesn;t work throwing some falsh error .

so i just wanna ask that

---

**"does flash only call gobal scoped javascript function"** ??

Comment: How about providing us with some code, and what that "some flash error" is?

Comment: my Question actually is "does flash only call gobal scoped javascript function" ?

 it didnt call my JavaScript function so "i assuemed may be some flash error :)"

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the JavaScript you want to execute in an anonymous function that you declare and call from ActionScript, like this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("function() { data.closeItem(); }");
```

It may seem a bit odd that the function gets called, executed, with the above syntax, it does, but if you prefer you could make the declaration and separate call more explicit, like this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("(function() { data.closeItem(); })()");
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer (iirc); "yes".

It might be possible to get around by calling

```
ExternalInterface.call("eval", "data.closeItem()")
```